# How to send the details of the link as a parameter to an jsp page

Tags: jsp

I am new to jsp and have to no idea how to do this. I have 50 images as hyper links in my jsp page and whenever the user clicks on a particular image,it should be redirected to another jsp page where the user can buy the product. Now how can i know which link has been clicked by the user? Please help with some code snippets. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using servlets, where you write your logic on which image the user clicks the link on. He is guided to the particular page where he can buy the product.
Basically you need to learn J2ee(servlets and DAO ie database connectivity).
Please do not expect code snippets here.
Until & unless you have a code and we can work on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just embed whatever information you need to send to the server in the href of the link.  For example:

Your HTML would look like:

```
<a href="path/to/my/servlet/or/jsp?product_id=(the product id)"><img border="0" src="path/to/image"/></a>
```

Then in your servlet/controller/jsp, you can do something like:

```
String productId = request.getParameter("product_id");
```

to find out which product the user clicked on.